# Is it possible to resize a DateTimePicker or MonthCalendar Control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, calendar, resize, datetimepicker

Essentially I want to re-size my dateTimePicker control to fit its parent container. I have tried to do this both through the Control Editor and programmatically but I simply cannot get the drop down calendar to expand at all. So 2 part question:

a) Is this even possible to do?

b) Is there an easy-to-implement solution to having a good looking calendar that fits its parent field? (i.e. using a data grid or something similar)

Any help or knowledge is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

The size of both objects is fixed and defined by the size of its font. Thus you might change its size by affecting the font size. This works fine with `DateTimePicker` but does not seem to work with `MonthCalendar`. After a quick research I have found a pretty curious recommendation on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed1b187e-333c-4f31-9bde-d1a31737930f/how-do-i-resize-the-monthy-calander-control): "you can consider third party MonthCalendar controls to meet your requirement temporarily".

There are quite a few third-party options (after a really quick search I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar)) or you might even create one by your own. I personally haven't ever had any problem with the in-built controls but if the size is so important for you I guess that you would have to search/develop something by your own.

Further recommendation: rely on WPF which does contain a resizable control (`DatePicker`). I want to highlight here that I don't like WPF at all and that thus this recommendation is because I don't see any other option (inside .NET).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! @varocarbas; I actually knew about the font thing for the DateTimePicker, but I truly want to resize the drop down GUI part (the actual calendar itself) and it doesn't seem to be possible without using a 3rd party source. And monthCalendar is a fixed size control (I'm fairly certain of this now). But thanks anyways!!!

Comment: No problem. I have found your question interesting (have used these controls many times in the past, but haven't ever thought about the resizing problem).

Comment: It's supremely annoying because I am fairly certain that Android's datePicker can fit to its parent content as well as the window's metro app calendar control. (I vaguely remember using both and being able to easily re-size them to fit my needs)

Comment: I am sure that there are alternatives (even developed by Microsoft). I guess that for desktop-based programs (for what VS was meant, at least, when these controls were created), this resizing thing is not a big deal at all. I guess that is a "newer problem", more relevant for web-based and mobile-based programs. Bear in mind that it hasn't still been fixed (the link I included in my answer was written various years ago), most likely, because nobody really cared :)

Comment: Also... have you tried WPF? This sounds as the kind of "improvements" which it has introduced with respect to the standard VS.