# How to change dateTimePicker calendar size in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

How do I change the size of the calendar? If I change the font size of the dateTime picker, it incresses in size. But when I do it with the calendar font, it does not change the size of the calendar or the font.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What is this? WinForm? WPF? WebForms?

Comment: Seems like there is a work around for this, but not so straight forward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559074/setting-calendar-size-when-overriding-datetimepicker-to-add-week-numbers

Comment: yeah i know.. I was looking for something more straight forward :)

Comment: wpf or custom controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556698/is-it-possible-to-resize-a-datetimepicker-or-monthcalendar-control-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

[There is a very easy way that is to edit the MiniumSize in Properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOIgL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
dtp.Font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
```

That way You will change the size of field where the date is shown, but not the size of rectangle of the popup Calendar. So... it is not possible!

Answer (score -1):

Change Windows text size on "control panel > display"